# How to add the sticky pagination in Alfresco Datatable

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, alfresco

I need to display sticky pagination using Alfresco Data Table. Pagination is at the bottom of the page but Alfresco Data Table is scrollbar.

```
<div class="content-container">
  <perfect-scrollbar>
    <adf-datatable #demoTable [data]="data" [loading]="demo" >
        </adf-datatable>
         <adf-pagination [pagination]="pagination" ></adf-pagination>
  </perfect-scrollbar>
  </div>
```